# Getting "ERROR DefaultExtensionsRegistry - Error instantiating extensions registry for fonts" during first application start

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using *JasperReports 3.7.2*, *iReport 3.7.2* and *JRE 1.6.0.20*.

First when I generate report to *PDF* I got following error (report is however correctly generated):

```
2012-08-24 10:03:49,302 [http-8180-1] ERROR DefaultExtensionsRegistry - Error instantiating extensions registry for fonts
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.awt.FontFormatException: bad table, tag=1146308935
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:73)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.createFontFace(SimpleFontFamily.java:316)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setNormal(SimpleFontFamily.java:85)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:233)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:204)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:173)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:142)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory.createRegistry(SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory.java:63)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:238)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:213)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:162)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:132)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:104)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:76)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:182)
```

Subseqent attempts to generate *PDF* are succesful without error.
Error occurs only first time generation of *PDF* after running application.

Error is not related to OS, it occurs on *Windows* as well as *UNIX* (*AIX* and *Linux*).

Please can someone give me clue to resolve this mis(t)ery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of the fonts in your jar files isn't parseable. I know you will never read this comment but it seems obvious. It just skips that font and afterwards it doen't try to read the font extensions again.